# Initialize val on a scalatest fixture

Tags: scala, scalatest

I'm writing my first `Funspec` and want to use the same fixture for several tests, but still want to use a new instance on each one. For that I use the `BeforeAndAfter` trait. My problem is I don't know how to refer initialization of the object under test to the `before` method and still store it in a `val` to make it final. The current looks like:

```
class CarTest extends FunsSpec with BeforeAndAfter{

  var car:Car = _

  before { 
      car = Car("BMW i3")
  }

  describe("A car") {

     it("can accelerate") { //do some stuff with car }

     it("can break") { //do some other stuff with car}

  }
}
```

So, the question is: Is there some way to make `car`  a `val` and still get it initialized before each method with `ScalaTest`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using a fixture like so:

```
import org.scalatest.FunSpec
import org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfter
import org.scalatest.fixture

case class Car(model:String)
class CarTest extends fixture.FunSpec{

  type FixtureParam = Car
  def withFixture(test: OneArgTest) {
    val car = Car("BMW")
    test(car)
  }

  describe("A car") {

     it("can accelerate") { car =>

     }

     it("can break") { car =>

     }
  }
}
```

Comment: I finally got the time to try it out. It's pretty much what i was looking for, shame that you need to specify the parameter on each test ( `car => ` ). Still, very good to learn about `fixture` package, thanks.